# Last user Access Cognos 7.5

Tags: cognos

Do you know if it is possible to find out last log in date/time for users in Cognos 7.5?

I am trying to find where I can locate the last date/time a user logged in. My Access Manager does not contain that information. We use SunOne Directory for Cognos 7.5

Comment: In Cognos 7.5, what are you logging into? Powerplay thick client? Impromptu? A web front end?

Comment: How do I check what I am logging into?

Comment: SunOne is an identity manager for many Cognos products (and other products besides). I'm not aware of it saving the last login date, however some Cognos products will log your activity. For example you can turn logging on in Powerplay, ReportNet, Cognos 8 and 10, but you can't in Impromptu. I am making the assumption that the last login date isn't in SunOne, but I might be wrong. Have you browsed the SunOne data to see?